# Differences in AbsoluteTiming for similar codes

Tags: permutation, numerical-value, timing

Consider the two following codes with the same `SeedRandom` (which ensures the same set of random numbers) but different use of the `AbsoluteTiming`

First one:

```
SeedRandom[1234]

Take[AbsoluteTiming[Permutations[RandomReal[1, 8]]], 1]

(* output 0.0019366 *)
```

Second one:

```
 SeedRandom[1234]

    AbsoluteTiming[Permutations[RandomReal[1, 8]]]

    (* large output with the first no: 0.000913217, this should be
    compared with the answer for first code *)
```

My questions are:

1) Why does the result for `AbsoluteTiming` vary for different runs even though the `SeedRandom` remain the same?

2) Why does the output from the second code (see above) takes a noticeably longer time than the first? It gets worse when I increase "8" to "9"?

Comment: (1) Imprecision of the timing perhaps, or simple variation in the state of the machine?  (2) The Front End takes a significant amount of time formatting expressions for display, sometimes far longer than the calculation itself.

Comment: If you evaluate the "first one" a second time, it'll have a timing similar to the "second one".